# Dark, Underexposed Photos with Android Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera2

I am writing a data collection application for a research project, that takes photos quietly using the new Camera2 API without showing a preview. The issue is that all the photos are severely underexposed, usually totally black with faint outlines of room features. This is particularly an issue because my use case would involve taking photos of indoor environments. This is my capture code:

```
private void setupCamera(){
    assert mCamera != null;
    Log.d("Camera Status", "setting up...");
    ArrayList<Surface> s = new ArrayList<Surface>();
    assert mSurface != null;
    try {
        CaptureRequest.Builder builder = mCamera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        builder.addTarget(mSurface);
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, false);
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, 6);

        final CaptureRequest request = builder.build();
        s.add(mSurface);
        Log.d("Camera Status", "Creating Capture Session...");
        mCamera.createCaptureSession(s, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    Log.d("AE PRECAPTURE TRIGGER", request.get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER) + "");

                    session.capture(request, new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {

                            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                            context.updateStatus("Capture Successful");
                            Log.d("Capture Result", "Success");
                            mCamera.close();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureFailure failure) {
                            super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
                            Log.d("Capture Result", "Failure");
                            context.updateStatus("Capture Failed");
                        }
                    }, context.handler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

            }
        }, context.handler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Do you call this function on each shoot? If so, it looks like camera can not get exposure parameters adapted to environment, because CaptureSession is recreated each time. Also CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_STARTused to start exposure parameters searching, so it shouldn't be used in STILL capture request.

Comment: Yes I call this function each time I take a photo. So, should I create the capture session once and then just pass requests to it?

Comment: It worked, thanks :)